# Is there a formula to find the largest value of two adjacent cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of data representing total sales by month from column B to column  M. I'd like to create a formula that can find the largest sum of two adjacent cells.

Example

1,3,4,6,6,1,9,2,5,2,1,4

I would want the formula to state 12 (6+6) as the answer, I've only been able to come up with a formula that returns "11" representing the (9+2).

I tried a formula that found the largest value and then used a second formula for finding the larger value of the adjacent cells. I did not take into account that the largest number and it's adjacent cell does not always equate to the largest sum of two adjacent cells.

I used a total of 4 formulas

I used =LARGE(B17:M17,1) in cell R17 and then in Q19 and R19 i used =INDEX(B17:M17,MATCH(R17,B17:M17,0)-1) and =INDEX(B17:M17,MATCH(R17,B17:M17,0)+1) and for the final formula i used =R17+LARGE(Q19:R19,1) –

Comment: Show us your formula.

Comment: Put it in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use INDEX in its array model and offset one array.

```
=MAX(INDEX(A1:K1+B1:L1, , ))
```

[image]

Comment: That is very interesting! Did you stop at column I and J for a particular reason? I extended A1:K1 + B1:L1 in the event that the last two cells are the largest. This is a way i hadn't thought of thank you very much for simplifying it.

Comment: I put those ranges in by dragging cells on the worksheet but I was blocked from the true range by the function's hot tip. When I realized that, I fixed the formula but didn't redo the img.

Answer (score 2):

Use AGGREGATE:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,A1:K1+B1:L1,1)
```

[image]

or LARGE in an Array entry:

```
=LARGE(A1:K1+B1:L1,1)
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode

or MAX as an array:

```
=MAX(A1:K1+B1:L1)
```

Again, confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode

Comment: There is always more than one way!! Those both are very good solutions that I did not think of. Thank you sharing hopefully I can leverage all of this new information in the future.